# JavaScript function refuses to work on production server

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I am using the MM_goToURL() function which I borrowed from Macromedia Dreamweaver to send HTTP requests to specific URLs on the server. Below is the code for the function, it is declared in an external JavaScript file.

```
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments;document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}
```

I have a select combobox that is supposed to trigger the requests when it is changed.
Here is the static form of the code below. Note that it usually generated dynamically using JSP.

```
<select onchange="MM_goToURL('parent','statistics_servlet.mpcs?chart=Sales&chartType=Daily&weekSelected='+this.value);">  
       <option value="Jan 5, 2014" selected="selected">This week: Jan 5, 2014 to Jan 11, 2014</option>
       <option value="Dec 29, 2013">Last week: Dec 29, 2013 to Jan 4, 2014</option>
       <option value="Dec 22, 2013">Prev week: Dec 22, 2013 to Dec 28, 2013</option>
       <option value="Dec 15, 2013">Prev week: Dec 15, 2013 to Dec 21, 2013</option>
                     ...
                     ...
       <option value="Nov 10, 2013">Prev week: Nov 10, 2013 to Nov 16, 2013</option>
       <option value="Nov 3, 2013">Prev week: Nov 3, 2013 to Nov 9, 2013</option>
</select>
```

The code above works perfectly well on localhost server, but does not work on my production server/domain.

My domain name is "[www.royalseeds.org](http://www.royalseeds.org)" but it is set to forwarding & masking to the production server at http://idy777.s156.eatj.com/RoyalSeedsMPCS/

My users will have to use the domain name instead of the server URL since the domain name is more friendly. The URL to the page that is in question is http://www.royalseeds.org/statistics_servlet.mpcs but the combobox refuses to send the request when changed.

Obviously this isn't a Servlet/JSP problem, my suspicion goes to the domain name fowarding/masking mechanism.

I also tested the page with this URL http://idy777.s156.eatj.com/RoyalSeedsMPCS/statistics_servlet.mpcs and it works perfectly well like my

```
http://localhost:8080/RoyalSeedsMPCS/statistics_servlet.mpcs
```

**So, my question is: what can I do to solve this problem?**

**Edit:**
I have disabled the filters for the specified page/servlet which is http://idy777.s156.eatj.com/RoyalSeedsMPCS/statistics_servlet.mpcs or http://www.royalseeds.org/statistics_servlet.mpcs so to enable access to the page. But I will enable it after 24 hours for security reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Does your server support the mpcs extensions?

Comment: Ahhh! The mpcs extensions? Those are just URL names mapped to a servlet. They do not mean anything.

Comment: No clue then :) Sorry!